# Whats going on with my lawn? Grass or weed?

Tags: grass, weeds

Lawn:
[image]

Close up of lawn after a mow:
[image]

Grass pulled out:
[image]

So if you look at the 3 pictures can you tell me if its grass growing and if so which type? Or is this weeds?

I bought the coated Scotts seed mix from Costco and this was seeded last fall. This is in Toronto, Canada.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the seed head displayed in the last image it could be either a ryegrass (probably) or a fescue (not so probably), either of which would likely have been in the mix of seed. The absence of healthy spreading underground spreading stolons leans away from bluegrass, but in any event definitely a desirable grass type for Toronto. Further examination would produce more different grass types, one of which would become dominant over time.

Comment: Any idea why the roots are so thick and now turning yellow? I wonder if its because I let the grass grow too tall that one time. Just doesn't have that grass feel i was hoping for but i read these types of grass need less maintenance? If true at least thats great